# JavaScript setAttribute on another element

Tags: javascript, element, extern, setattribute

I have a problem to set an attribute on another element.

I'm using PHP code with JS and HTML and it looks like:

```
<textarea name='$id' id='$id' class='regular-text' cols='60' rows='1' tabindex='2'"
            . "onkeypress =\"javascript:document.getElementById('content').setAttribute('onkeypress', document.getElementById('so_observer_heading_count').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').value.length)\">$value</textarea>
```

You must know I have 2 elements. The first('content') one I use for writing a text and in the other one('so_observer_heading_count') there shall be updated the number of signs from the first element.

So my question is, how can I set an attribute on another element.

I have already checked that the name is correct and when i change the content of the textarea on the 2. element I get the right amount from the first element. But I want only to change content in the first element to refresh the amount.

And I don't want to change the code of the first element! And don't be confused by the textarea, in future this shall be a label or something else.

Comment: Could we see the rest of your html? Also, I'm rather confused on why you want to change an attribute to the same thing every time someone presses a key.

Comment: Well it's a Wordpress plugin, to completely post it here would be too much. The question is, if it's possible to do and if my idea the right one for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

Don't use the inline-eventbindings. Always use "real" javascript, (this way you also prevent the problem of escaping your quotes) this is far more cleaner and more maintanable.

Also you code has another problem: You have an eventhandler "keypress" on the textarea, which binds on every "keypress" another attribute to your content-element. This is not very performant and most likey won't work properly. This code should be everything you need:

```
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener("keyup",function(){

    var obs  = document.getElementById('so_observer_heading_count');    

    obs.innerHTML = this.value.length;

});​
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/EF9zT/)** for you.

Edit: I changed the event from `keypress` to `keyup` to 1) count properly 2) take charakter deletion into account.

Comment: You forgot to remove an errant quote in your fiddle, just a heads up.

Comment: You code is looking very well. But I don't know where to write it down. Could you help me. here is the full function.

Comment: @kwoxer sry, that code looks incredibly messy. I can't see any element called "content" in that code. Does **[this](http://pastebin.com/Ra1KbmiB)** work for you?

Comment: @kwoxer if it doesn't - could you set up an example fiddle of how your page looks like and then we will tweak it accordingly.

Comment: Nop, and I want as I said the event on the content box, not on my "new" area. Hard to explain. You had already Wordpress and know the box when you are editing or creating something. I'm doing a screenshot.

Comment: okay, then where do you create the content element? Bind the keyhandler directly to the "content"-element if you want the event on it.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/seooptimization.png/ I don't create the content box, it's a Wordpress thing. Is it not possible to easily get an event on the top box? The Textarea at the moment is the bottom one. Rest(title, desctiption etc, is working properly). But with the headings I want to get the actual changes from the content box.

Comment: Tried it but also not working, not even in my textarea on the bottom.

Comment: And could I ask why you are escaping the '' I don't think that you have to do it right there. And if I look on the HTML source code, it looks also a bit strange with these more quotes. And yeah with them nothing is working =/ If you want to test the plugin just let me know. =)

Comment: Ohh sorry my fail, I was a bit confused. But the code with the script also not working =/

Comment: Always parsing error with the script code. Could you test it my friend?

Comment: Could fix that problem, missing sign, at your ending script was a "/"missing. But yes as I told before, there is no working key event anyway. Also tried taking alert function instead, but same issue.

Comment: try to wrap the function into a `window.onload = function(){ /*the code*/ }`

Comment: Could you post the full method code please, I tried it and got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\seo-optimization\modules\headings\headings.php on line 40"

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('keyup',function(){document.getElementById('so_observer_heading_count').innerHTML = this.value.length;});}<script>

Comment: Let me show you how my HTML Code is looking like: `<td><textarea name="_so_observer_heading" id="_so_observer_heading" class="regular-text" cols="60" rows="1" tabindex="2"></textarea><br><script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('keyup',function(){document.getElementById('so_observer_heading_count').innerHTML = this.value.length;});}</script>You’ve entered <strong id="so_observer_heading_count">0</strong> heading1. .....
</td>` and still the same like before window.onload

Comment: It's too bad that nothing is working, maybe it not possible. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: well, I'm really sorry. But with this little information it's too hard to detect the problem remotely. Perhaps you manage to fix it on your own. I'm pretty sure, this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "setAttribute" won't work on a method. Try instead :

```
 document.getElementById('content').onkeypress = function() { document.getElementById('so_observer_heading_count').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').value.length };
```

Comment: What method, precisely is the OP trying to use it on?  I don't see any thing to that effect..

Comment: I want to parse a textbox for SEO optimization. Therefor I need a change event on the main box.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are certainly more.. efficient ways of doing this, but the thing you forgot to do was escape your single quotes, so the js treats your event as a string, instead of parsing the end result:

```
<textarea name='$id' id='$id' class='regular-text' cols='60' rows='1' tabindex='2'"
        . "onkeypress =\"document.getElementById('content').setAttribute('onkeypress', 'document.getElementById(\'so_observer_heading_count\').innerHTML = document.getElementById(\'content\').value.length;')\">$value</textarea>
```

Elsewise..  I would personally do this through an included js file that executes the above line on document load/ready, versus every time a key is pressed.

Update: slight edit so anything I removed from your above code was added back, incase you want to just straight-copy it in.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. And the thing is that I don't really want a keypress event on the 2. textarea. I need something diffrent like this from Cristoph

Comment: Cristoph's answer is the way to go.